# I'm getting read access violation when i try to push to a vector in a lambda function

Tags: c++

Exception thrown: read access violation.
**_My_data** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7.

i get this exception when i run this code:

```cpp
b.setOnAction([&](Bullet* b)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Bullet b1;
            b1.init();
            bullets.push_back(b1);
        }
    }
);
```

it works when adding one bullet:

```
b.setOnAction([&](Bullet* b)
    {
        Bullet b1;
        b1.init();
        bullets.push_back(b1);
    }
);
```

`setOnAction` sets a std::function variable inside the Bullet class that it calls in its update function.

here is the Bullet class:

```
class Bullet
{
private:
    std::function<void(Bullet*)> mOnAction;

public:
    
    void setOnAction(std::function<void(Bullet*)> func) { mOnAction = func; };

    void init()
    {
        mOnAction = [](Bullet* b) {};
    }

    void update()
    {
        mOnAction(this);
    }
};
```

`bullets` is a vector full of Bullet Objects.

Here is the main function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<Bullet> bullets;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Bullet b;
        b.init();
        b.setOnAction([&](Bullet* b)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Bullet b1;
                    b1.init();
                    bullets.push_back(b1);
                }
            }
        );
        bullets.push_back(b);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = bullets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Bullet& b = bullets[i];
            b.update();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**I managed to fix this by adding bullets to a temporary vector and adding from the temporary vector to the main bullets vector**

Something like this:

```cpp
**// Temporary vector created besides main bullets vector
std::vector<Bullet> bulletsToAdd;**


b.setOnAction([&](Bullet* b)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Bullet b1;
                    b1.init();
                    **//Add to the temp vector
                    bulletsToAdd.push_back(b1);**
                }
            }
        );

while (true)
{
    **// Add everything In the temp vector to the main vector
    for (auto& b : bulletsToAdd)
        bullets.push_back(b);
    // Reset temp vector
    bulletsToAdd.clear();**

    for (int i = bullets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Bullet& b = bullets[i];
        b.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Start by using a debugger to catch the crash, and locate when and where in your code it happens. Then examine variables and their values to make sure they all look valid.

Comment: my guess would be that `bullets` is a dangling reference

Comment: `_My_data was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7.` probably iterating over a container that no longer exists.

Comment: @G.M. but I am pushing 10 Bullets  before the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

The reference `Bullet& b` in `main` is only valid as long as `bullets` isn't resized, when the capacity of `bullets` increases all objects are deleted. The `mOnAction` member that you are calling through therefore becomes invalid when you `push_back` too many elements. As the references captured in the lambda are stored in the `std::function` your code crashes when it tries to access the `bullets` reference.

Address sanitizer can help debug these issues by crashing as soon as possible after your code has done something wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/a83Pd9e85

Comment: So what can i do to avoid this?

Comment: There are a few options, preset the capacity of your vector so it never grows. A better option to to re-architect your code so you're not reliant on having a reference to an item in a vector whilst simultaneously modifying that vector

Comment: vectors are bad container for entities in game environment. Every change of capachy causes    whole thing to be copied